# is there is any way to build hybrid app (Ionic, AngularJs, Cordova) in android studio

Tags: angularjs, cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am native android application developer working on java and android api's with android studio, recently i got a requirement to build a hybrid app with ionic, cordova and angularJs, i spent 5-6 hours and dig google to get some tutorail to setup a project structure of hybrid app in andorid studio, but haven't found anything.

I know how to use ionic, angular and cordova but don't know about the project structure and setup compiling and how to run.

so, i want you guys to post links of such tutorails (If you have any).

Comment: check [this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/platforms/android/index.html) documentation using CLI mode in this they have mentioned how to use phonegap in AS.

Comment: Mr. Closer, can i  know the reason of closing this question?

Comment: there is no built in way of building hybrid apps from android studio, but you don't need android studio at all, using the CLI you can create, run and build the apps

Comment: I'm Mr. Closer, the reason is you are asking for links to tutorials "i want you guys to post links of such tutorails" and that's a reason to close  "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.". And answers with links to tutorials will be deleted by moderators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello try to reefer this articles on mcgivery blog.
http://mcgivery.com/100-ionic-framework-resources/
I'm ionic dev and if you want to use good IDE use WebStorm :) 
I'm using it on EAP version.

Comment: is there is any tutorail that can help me in writing just a hello world app with webstorm with ionic.

Comment: Webstorm itself give a complete ionic project structure, we have have to add platforms Android/iOS.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look over `cordova` CLI mode. In this see specific for `Android Platform` for that you first need following pre-requirement to use:

1. [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio).
2. [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools).
3. [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)
4. [Git Client](http://git-scm.com/)

After installing `Node.js` Open it's terminal and follow command to create `Cordova` project with different platform. These steps are already mentioned in [official documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/cli/index.html).

Once you have created executed `cordova build android`command then browse to your project directory. In that you will find that there's a directory named `platforms` in that you will see `Android`, now open your `Android Studio` in that select **Select Import Project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc).** when you create a new project from there browse to `Android` directory. That's all you need to do for `cordova`

Official documentation and referrals links:

http://ionicframework.com/docs/overview/#download

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/platforms/android/index.html

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/cli/index.html

https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/started

Answer (score 0):

> first of all you have to install 1)node.js 2)apache ANT 3) Java JDK &
>   JRE 4) Android SDk & Eclipse and then after all installation you have
>   to set this all software path into environmental- variable. and then
>   fire your npm install -g ionic. without this all software
>   installation and there path setup your ionic application will not
>   created. and still you have any confusion and any question related
>   software installation and there path setup then again tell me i will
>   help you.

Comment: i already setup all the things sir, all i want to know the project setup in android studio